# Rails: How to hard code field in a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a Rails project that has nested resources as defined below.

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :entries
  end
```

For the `entries#new` form, I would like to hard code the `project_id` from the path `projects/project_id/entries/new` as the `project_id` field of `form_for` in the entries' views directory. When I write:

```
= f.label :project_id
%br
= f.select :project_id, @project
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for #<Project:0x007fa9adc06120>
```

Any ideas how to send the @project as that field to the form without getting f.select errors? I believe f.select takes a colleciton and so it doesn't like me just giving it a single object as its second parameter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your @entry object in your form is built well (with the project_id), you can use `f.hidden_field :project_id` or eventually: `f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id`

Comment: @MrYoshiji that worked splendidly! thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have your `@entry` in the new method of your controller, something like this:

```
def new
  @entry = Entry.new
  # etc.
```

You can use this instead:

```
def new
  @entry = @project.entries.build
  # it will set project_id to the @project.id
```

and in the view:

```
= f.hidden_field :project_id
```

If you don't want to initialize with the project_id directly in the view:

```
= f.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id
```